# How to Show Eastern Letter(Chinese Character) on SQL Server/SQL Reporting Services?

Tags: sql-server, unicode

I need to insert chinese characters in my database but it always show ???? ..

Example:

Insert this record.

微波室外单元-Apple

Then it became ???

Result:

??????-Apple

I really Need Help...thanks in regard.

I am using MSSQL Server 2008

Comment: can u please mention which SQL version you using, i.e MSSql-2002 or MSSql2005 or MSSql-2008

Comment: What is a "Microwave outdoor unit"? (compliments of translate.google.com)

Comment: Any chance you could share with us what the solution was for you? Was it the need for a unicode column (or "native" as the n in nvarchar means)?

Comment: What i ve done is to add eastern language on regional settings on control panel on winsows xp. after that i just change my data type to nvarchar and it works to display Chinese Character on Report. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding the appropriate languages to your Windows locale setings. you'll have to make sure your development machine is set to display Non-Unicode characters in the appropriate language.
And ofcourse u need to use NVarchar for foreign language feilds

Answer (score 15):

Make sure you specify a unicode string with a capital N when you insert like:

```
INSERT INTO Table1 (Col1) SELECT N'微波室外单元-Apple' AS [Col1]
```

and that Table1 (Col1) is an NVARCHAR data type.

Comment: SQL-server is case insensitve

Answer (score 6):

Make sure the column you're inserting to is **nchar**, **nvarchar**, or **ntext**. If you insert a Unicode string into an ANSI column, you really will get question marks in the data.

Also, be careful to check that when you pull the data back out you're not just seeing a client display problem but are actually getting the question marks back:

```
SELECT Unicode(YourColumn), YourColumn FROM YourTable
```

Note that the Unicode function returns the code of only the *first* character in the string.

Once you've determined whether the column is really storing the data correctly, post back and we'll help you more.

Comment: Did you mean ANSI os ASCII column?

Comment: I meant ANSI. Try a search for [ANSI vs Unicode](http://google.com/?q=ANSI+vs+Unicode) for understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have set an encoding for the database to one that supports these characters. UTF-8 is the *de facto* encoding as it's ASCII compatible but supports all 1114111 Unicode code points.

Comment: SQL Server doesn't do UTF-8. It's a Microsoft thing, they always want you to use UTF-16 for Unicode instead, which means using the `NVARCHAR` etc string types.

Comment: Gah, that sucks. Sorry, I didn't know that as I come from a general/MySQL background.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT 'UPDATE table SET msg=UNISTR('''||ASCIISTR(msg)||''') WHERE id='''||id||''' FROM table WHERE id= '123344556' ;
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64340533/edit) your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Also this seem as not valid sql syntax