# PDO DBLIB multibyte (chinese) character encoding - SQL server

Tags: sql-server, pdo, character-encoding, freetds, multibyte

On a Linux machine, I am using PDO DBLIB to connect to an MSSQL database and insert data in a `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` table. The problem is that when I am trying to insert chinese characters (multibyte) they are inserted as `å“ˆå¸‚é¦™åŠåŒºç æ±Ÿè·¯å·`.

My (part of) code is as follows:

```
$DBH = new PDO("dblib:host=$myServer;dbname=$myDB;", $myUser, $myPass);

$query = "
    INSERT INTO UserSignUpInfo
    (FirstName)
    VALUES
    (:firstname)";

$STH = $DBH->prepare($query);

$STH->bindParam(':firstname', $firstname);
```

What I've tried so far:

1. Doing `mb_convert_encoding` to `UTF-16LE` on `$firstname` and CAST as VARBINARY in the query like:

   `$firstname = mb_convert_encoding($firstname, 'UTF-16LE', 'UTF-8');`

   ```
   VALUES
   (CAST(:firstname AS VARBINARY));
   ```

   Which results in inserting the characters properly, until there are some not-multibyte characters, which break the PDO execute.
2. Setting my connection as utf8:

   ```
   $DBH = new PDO("dblib:host=$myServer;dbname=$myDB;charset=UTF-8;", $myUser, $myPass);
   $DBH->exec('SET CHARACTER SET utf8');
   $DBH->query("SET NAMES utf8");
   ```
3. Setting `client charset` to UTF-8 in my freetds.conf

   Which had no impact.

Is there any way at all, to insert multibyte data in that SQL database? Is there any other workaround? *I've thought of trying PDO ODBC or even mssql, but thought it's better to ask here before wasting any more time.*

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

I ended up using [MSSQL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mssql.php) and the `N` data type prefix. I will swap for and try PDO_ODBC when I have more time. Thanks everyone for the answers!

Comment: Excuse me for my question, but some times collation of a field is different of collation of table, so I want to know **type** and **collation** of your field; plz.

Comment: Do you test the `nvarchar()` or `ntext` ?

Comment: According to [this](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-dblib.php#109439) you can convert the data first and then insert. The link does something like this: `$STH->bindValue(':value', iconv('UTF-8', 'ISO8859-1', $value));`. It is similar to your question's first item under *What I've Tried So Far*. I am not clear on what the column type you are inserting into, so this may not work.

Comment: @chuex I tried that solution, and can verify that it unfortunately doesn't work

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Is there any way at all, to insert multibyte data in [this particular] SQL
>   database? Is there any other workaround?

1. If you can switch to PDO_ODBC, Microsoft provides free SQL Server ODBC drivers for Linux (only for 64-bit Red Hat Enterprise Linux, and 64-bit SUSE Linux Enterprise) which support Unicode.
2. If you can change to PDO_ODBC, then the N-prefix for inserting Unicode is going to work.
3. If you can change the affected table from `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` to `UTF-8` (which is the default for MSSQL), then that would be ideal.

Your case is more restricted. This solution is suited for the case when you have mixed multibyte and non-multibyte characters in your input string, and you need to save them to a Latin table, and the `N` data type prefix isn't working, and you don't want to change away from PDO DBLIB (because Microsoft's Unicode PDO_ODBC is [barely supported](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh568451(v=sql.110).aspx) on linux). Here is one workaround.

Conditionally encode the input string as **base64**. After all, that's how we can safely transport pictures in line with emails.

**Working Example:**

```
$DBH = new PDO("dblib:host=$myServer;dbname=$myDB;", $myUser, $myPass);

$query = "
INSERT INTO [StackOverflow].[dbo].[UserSignUpInfo]
           ([FirstName])
     VALUES
           (:firstname)";

$STH = $DBH->prepare($query);

$firstname = "输入中国文字！Okay!";

/* First, check if this string has any Unicode at all */
if (strlen($firstname) != strlen(utf8_decode($firstname))) {
    /* If so, change the string to base64. */
    $firstname = base64_encode($firstname);
}

$STH->bindParam(':firstname', $firstname);
$STH->execute();
```

Then to go backwards, you can test for base64 strings, and decode *only* them without damaging your existing entries, like so:

```
while ($row = $STH->fetch()) {
    $entry = $row[0];

    if (base64_encode(base64_decode($entry , true)) === $entry) {

         /* Decoding and re-encoding a true base64 string results in the original entry */
         print_r(base64_decode($entry) . PHP_EOL);

    } else {

         /* Previous entries not encoded will fall through gracefully */
         print_r($entry  . PHP_EOL);
    }
}
```

Entries will be saved like this:

```
Guan Tianlang
5pys6Kqe44KS5a2maGVsbG8=
```

But you can easily convert them back to:

```
Guan Tianlang
输入中国文字！Okay!
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort in writing this answer! Unfortunately, the system that retrieves the data after they get stored in the DB, is on .NET and I have no access. Nevertheless, this is a sweet workaround.

Answer (score 2):

Collation shouldn't matter here.

Double-byte characters need to be stored in `nvarchar`, `nchar`, or `ntext` fields.  You don't need to perform any casting.

The `n` data type prefix stands for National, and it causes SQL Server to store text as Unicode (UTF-16).

**Edit:**

PDO_DBLIB does not support Unicode, and is now deprecated.

If you can switch to PDO_ODBC, Microsoft provides free SQL Server ODBC drivers for Linux which support Unicode.

[Microsoft - SQL Server ODBC Driver Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh568451(v=sql.110).aspx)

[Blog - Installing and Using the Microsoft SQL Server ODBC Driver for Linux](http://strangenut.com/blogs/dacrowlah/archive/2012/04/13/installing-and-using-the-microsoft-sql-server-odbc-driver-for-linux.aspx)

Comment: Just tried using mssql_query with PHP and N'', and it worked fine. I wonder if there is any way to make PDO_DBLIB work like that...

Comment: This article on php.net says that PDO_DBLIB is deprecated, and recomends using SqlSrv on Windows and PDO_ODBC elsewhere.  http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-dblib.php.  Can you try PDO_ODBC?

Comment: While it may be deprecated, this doesn't really help the OP with PDO_DBLIB. He's looking for a workaround first.

Comment: Not sure I agree.  OP actually mentioned using alternate drivers.  I think it's a much better solution to use drivers which natively support what OP needs than to try and hack something together with an aging driver which is no longer supported.

Comment: The MS driver is for 64-bit Red Hat Enterprise Linux, and 64-bit SUSE Linux Enterprise. He's going to have to change his whole box! :)

Comment: Lol, change his whole box from what exactly?  He didn't specify, but Red Hat and SUSE dominate the Linux Server market.  Fedora should be no problem, and here's an article about a [successful Ubuntu installation](http://onefinepub.com/2013/03/ms-sql-odbc-ubuntu/).

Comment: Your solution is the most sound if he can get everything set up. I agree workarounds aren't perfect, but it was fun to come up with this solution. I originally downvoted this answer, but I have undone that now. Apologies. Seems every answer got downvoted... except Imran's. Suspicious.

Comment: PDO_DBLIB is deprecated on Windows, on Linux it is still an option to consider

Answer (score 1):

You can use Unicode compatible data-type for the table column for supporting foreign languages(exceptions are shown in EDIT 2).

> (char, varchar, text)  **Versus**  (nchar, nvarchar, ntext)

**Non-Unicode :**

Best suited for US English: "One problem with data types that use 1 byte to encode each character is that the data type can only represent 256 different characters. This forces multiple encoding specifications (or code pages) for different alphabets such as European alphabets, which are relatively small. It is also impossible to handle systems such as the Japanese Kanji or Korean Hangul alphabets that have thousands of characters

**Unicode**

Best suited for systems that need to support at least one foreign language: "The Unicode specification defines a single encoding scheme for most characters widely used in businesses around the world. All computers consistently translate the bit patterns in Unicode data into characters using the single Unicode specification. This ensures that the same bit pattern is always converted to the same character on all computers. Data can be freely transferred from one database or computer to another without concern that the receiving system will translate the bit patterns into characters incorrectly.

Example :

Also i have tried one example you can view its screens below,it would be helpful for issues relating the foreign language insertions as the question is right now.The column as seen below in `nvarchar` and it do support the Chinese language

[image]

EDIT 1:

Another related issue is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3682156/how-to-show-eastern-letterchinese-character-on-sql-server-sql-reporting-servic)

EDIT 2 :

Unicode unsupported scripts are shown [here](http://unicode.org/standard/unsupported.html)

Answer (score -1):

just use nvarchar, ntext, nChar and when you want to insert then
use

```
INSERT INTO UserSignUpInfo
    (FirstName)
    VALUES
    (N'firstname');
```

`N` will refer to Unicode charactor and it is standard world wide.

Ref :

https://aalamrangi.wordpress.com/2012/05/13/storing-and-retrieving-non-english-unicode-characters-hindi-czech-arabic-etc-in-sql-server/

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191200(v=sql.105).aspx

https://irfansworld.wordpress.com/2011/01/25/what-is-unicode-and-non-unicode-data-formats/

Comment: OP said "Just tried using mssql_query with PHP and N'', and it worked fine. I wonder if there is any way to make PDO_DBLIB work like that". Please read his other comments carefully.

Answer (score -2):

This link Explain of chinese character in MYSQL. [Can't insert Chinese character into MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14456313/cant-insert-chinese-character-into-mysql) .
You have to  create table table_name () `CHARACTER SET = utf8;`
`Use UTF-8` when you insert to table

```
set username utf8; INSERT INTO table_name (ABC,VAL);
```

abd create Database in  `CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;`

then You can insert in chinese character in table

Comment: The table is `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` and unfortunately it cannot be changed - it is part of a huge corporate system.

Comment: `mysql_query("SET character_set_client=utf8", $dbLink)or die(mysql_error());
        mysql_query("SET character_set_connection=utf8", $dbLink)or die(mysql_error());` try like this